# Can I make jQuery read tag helpers of ASP.NET Core 2.1 ? Seems it's completely ignoring them

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Can jQuery read the asp-for tag helpers and `asp-action`? It seems from what I've seen that just ignores them how can I get around this problem or solve it? (I can't change jQuery approach).

What can I do guys? Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do: displaying those elements and at the same time saving some values in database (be aware I have to append multiple elements)?

```
$('#results').append('<form method="post"><div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">'
                    + '<div class="thumbnail">'
                    + '<iframe width="100%" height="200px" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '"></iframe>'
                    + '<div class="caption">'
                    + '<p class=" group inner list-group-item-text" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:elipsis;white-space:nowrap;">' + vidTitle + '</p>'
                    + '<div class="row">'
                    + '<input type="text" value="' + id + '" asp-for="Input.vLink" hidden />'
                    + '<input type="text" value="' + vidTitle + '" asp-for="Input.vLink" hidden />' 
                    + '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">'
                    + '<button asp-action="AddToPlaylist" type="submit" asp-route-vLink="' + id + '"asp-route-vTit="' + vidTitle + '" id="' + vidTitle + '" data-key="' + id + '" class="btn btn-success" onclick="AddToPlaylist()">Add to Playlist</button>'
                    + '</div></div></div></div></div></form>');
            })

 $('#playlist').append('<form method="post"><div">'
                + '<input type="text" value="' + id + '" asp-for="Input.vLink" hidden />'
                + '<input type="text" value="' + vidTitle + '" asp-for="Input.vLink" hidden />'
                + '<div class="list-inline"><li style="width:89%;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:elipsis;white-space:nowrap;list-style-type:none;">' +
                VideoTitulli + '  ' + id
                +'</li>'+' '+'<button value="' + id + '" style="border-radius:10px" class="fas fa-times" asp-action="RemoveFromPlaylist" asp-route-vLink="' + id + '"asp-route-vTit="' + vidTitle + '" onclick="RemoveFromPlaylist()"></button></div><hr class="hrC" /></div</form>')
```

.net core actions

```
public async Task AddToPlaylist(string userId)
{
    var userplaylist = new UserPlaylist() { ResultTitles = Input.vTit,ResultLinks = Input.vLink, ApplicationUserId = userId};
    _context.UPlaylist.AddAsync(userplaylist);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task RemoveFromPlaylist(string userId)
{
    var userplaylit = new UserPlaylist() { ResultTitles = Input.vTit, ResultLinks = Input.vLink, ApplicationUserId = userId };
   _context.UPlaylist.Remove(userplaylit);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding the difference between client-side code and server-side code.  Things like `asp-action="AddToPlaylist"` mean nothing on the client.  They're used server-side to generate the resulting markup/code that's sent to the client.  Open your browser's debugging tools to observe what's actually on the page there.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, Tag Helpers run server side to generate HTML for the client. JQuery can not see these Tag Helpers.

If you run HTML with Tag Helpers and look at the generated code, you'll see there's no `asp-` attributes, only HTML which the Tag Helpers have generated for you.

Therefore if you want to add HTML to the page, you'll need to do it manually instead.

For more information on Tag Helpers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1